Join points into lines, split by a date gap
I have data for the location and dates of a band's gigs as point features. I want to turn these into line features where the lines come from all points in time-order until there's a gap of a given size - this might be the end of a tour, for example. The time spacing between consecutive gigs is variable (might be one day, could be several), but maybe I want to split if there's a gap of two weeks.
Here's a sample gigs.geojson with ten gigs that break down into three tours (in this case, one in each year, so the divisions are clear):
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "sample",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Place": "A", "when": "1970-01-02" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Place": "B", "when": "1970-01-04" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2.0, 2.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Place": "C", "when": "1970-01-05" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 3.0, 3.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Place": "D", "when": "1971-05-28" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.0, 4.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Place": "E", "when": "1971-05-29" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 5.0, 5.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Place": "F", "when": "1971-05-30" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 6.0, 6.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Place": "G", "when": "1971-06-01" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 7.0, 7.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Place": "H", "when": "1972-04-02" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 8.0, 8.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Place": "I", "when": "1972-04-03" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 9.0, 9.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Place": "J", "when": "1972-04-04" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 10.0, 10.0 ] } }
]
}

What I'd like as output, in this case with a date gap of say, 10 days, would be three LINESTRING features, the first with three vertices (from A, B, and C) the second with four (D to G) and the third with three again (H, I, J).
Ideally it would be all done with SQL into a Virtual Layer so I can dynamically play with the date gap. Otherwise it might have to be a few processing steps. I did experiment with basic SQL functions like LAG to try and get the date difference between gigs but I couldn't see a way to split the points into groups to make line features from.
I could do this easily in standalone Python or R so don't waste your time solving it that way! A pure QGIS/SQL solution would be nice to have.
The real data has over 2000 points and is the geolocated gigs of Motörhead...

Sounds like a candidate for a geometry generator.

That would make it look right, but I think I actually need it as a layer since I might want to do additional styling and possibly export it as a geopackage/geojson for web mapping...

I also might want to do other things like draw within-country lines and across-water lines in a different style, but just getting the lines split as above would be a start...

For this to work you need to have your layer sorted by the date column.

Create a column holding the next rows date, name it next_event_date . My date column is named event_date

attributes(feature:= get_feature_by_id(layer:='gigs', feature_id:=@id+1))['event_date']

Create an integer column named group_reset which will be 0 when the difference between current date and next is less than 101, and 1 if more than 100. My date columns are of string type so I use to_date to convert them to date type.

case when
day(
to_date("next_event_date")-to_date("event_date"))>100 then 1
else 0
end


Create an int column named group which is the cumulative sum of group_reset column:

with_variable (
    'order',
    "event_date",
    sum( "group_reset", filter:="event_date"<=@order)
    )


Points to path with "group" as group expression.



I've not quite got this to work on my data yet but I don't doubt it works. I've probably just got a wrong name somewhere in my model, will debug and update! Thanks! Ah, my ordering is wrong...
